# yii2-mongodb syntax of update with use $pull

Tags: mongodb, yii2

Structure of record in a collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("577e3c801da29a8f2f8b4567"),
    "contacts": [
        { "id": NumberInt(7) },
        { "id": NumberInt(8) } 
    ],
    "user": NumberInt(10) 
}
```

It is necessary to delete in all records from contacts array, object with a certain id.

In Mongo the problem is solved by such request (for id = 7):

```
db.perimeter.update({ }, {$pull: {contacts: {id:7}}}, {multi: true})
```

How do I implement extenders in yii2-mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->updateAll(
    [ '$pull' => ['contacts' => ['id' => ['$in' => $contactIds] ] ] ],
    [ 'user' => $this->user ]
);
```

Where $contactIds - array of id-s for deleting objects (with these ids) from contacts.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = Category::findOne(['_id' => $id]);
    $key = array_search($parent_id, array_column($data->parent, 'id'));
    Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('category')->update(['_id' => $id], ['$pull' => [
            'parent' => $data->parent[$key]
    ]]);
```